# UWP set background color for GridView item's CheckBox

Tags: gridview, uwp, markup

I mean this gray square at the corner of 'Warlords':

[image]

Also i'd like to set one pixel border around it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer [GridViewItem style](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299127.aspx)

In that look for `MultiSelectSquare` `Border` control.
Below i have given background color of checkbox to Red

```
<Border x:Name="MultiSelectSquare"
                  Background="Red" BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="Black"
                  Width="20"
                  Height="20"
                  Margin="0,2,2,0"
                  VerticalAlignment="Top"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                  Visibility="Collapsed" >
```